# Were the Prophets of the Dark Side Sith Lords?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

In the *Jedi Prince* series, we see the prophets use some Force techniques, but were they Sith Lords, or just dark Force users?

Comment: There were powerful dark side users who weren't Sith, you know...

Comment: @Terriblefan I know, but I was was curious if they were actual Sith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clearly stated if **all** members are actual Force users but the Dark Force definitely had many members that were actual Sith or fallen Jedi (e.g. Kadann who became the supreme prophet). The founder of the cult, Darth Millennial, was definitely a Sith Lord.